# PyQGIS - Raster multiplication creates too large a file

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

When multiplying two rasters together using code in PyQGIS, the resultant raster is much larger than expected.

Each input raster takes up ~ 11KB as `.tif` files, but when I multiply two together it becomes a much larger `.tif` file, nearly 20MB, which seems way too big considering the input sizes.

Here is my code below to create the 20MB output raster:

```
expression = "r1@1 * r2@1"
combinedExtent = self.getCombinedExtent(layerList)
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression, outputPath, 'GTiff', combinedExtent, mainRaster.crs(), mainRaster.width(), mainRaster.height(), layerReferences)
calcResult = calc.processCalculation()
intersectLayer = QgsRasterLayer(outputPath, "Combined Raster layer")
```

With `outputPath` being where the output raster is saved, `combinedExtent` being the overall extent of both rasters in the calculation, and `mainRaster` being the overall background raster that both of the smaller rasters to be multiplied lie upon.

Below are the rasters used for multiplication, `r1` and `r2`, which are each roughly 14KB in size:

[image: r1, one of the rasters used for calculation]
[image: r2, the other raster used for calculations]

When multiplied with a similar raster, `r2`, the following is created, displaying the area of intersect between the two rasters:
[image: Raster output from multiplying two rasters]
But this file is roughly 20MB in size, which seems way too big considering the small size of both input rasters.

Hopefully you can download `r1` and `r2` as `.tifs` as attached and see the same issue with PyQGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QgsRasterCalculator outputs in FLOAT32 and that, unfortunately, cannot be changed.

FLOAT32 takes 4 bytes for each pixel, so you end with IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT * 4 bytes for your picture (plus some additional for header and such, this is just a rough estimate).

https://api.qgis.org/api/3.30/qgsrastercalculator_8cpp_source.html

---

What you can do to avoid it, is to use GDAL Raster Calculator in which you can adjust the output format.

[image]

[image]

You can call GDAL Raster Calculator from pyqgis.

Edit:

as @bugmenot123 mentioned, GDAL Raster Calculator also offers you to set compression on the output file, which can further lower the size of the file.

[image]

Comment: Compression is probably what makes them small, a Byte file would still be at least 20/4 -> 5MB. But that should also be possible to set when using the Processing tool instead of QgsRasterCalculator.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to mention that part. There are many more options available when using GDAL Raster Calculator than there are in QgsRasterCalculator which has most options hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks @ViperMiniQ, I'll have a look into that.